# Thinkbook 14S IWL screen flickering issue

Tags: lenovo-laptop, dead-pixel

I purchased a Thinkbook 14S IWL from USA and realized that it has a screen that flickers randomly. Here's a video of the same: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfNUeFf9D6I&feature=youtu.be

I have tried updating the drivers as well as the OS and also the BIOS but to no avail. I have already contacted the Lenovo support and waiting for a response from them.

Does anyone has any other solutions, meanwhile? 
[Reddit Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lenovo/comments/daetib/lenovo_thinkbook_14s_iwl_screen_flickering/)

**Update**:
I noticed that the issue aggravates when the WIFI is turned on and rarely occurs when the WIFI is turned off.

**Update 2**
Changing the *Transmit Power* property of the WIFI driver from *Highest* to *Medium-High* reduces the flicker
[image: Transmit power]

**Update 3** 2 dead pixels have now popped up on the screen. I ahven't received anything helpful from Lenovo yet.
[image]

Comment: In this case, Lenovo is likely the best choice.  Go to the Lenovo support page for you machine (model type) and look through the list of drivers (many). Make sure Chipset and ME Firmware have both been updated along with any others that the Update Package did not catch.

Comment: Will check the chipset. Thanks!

Comment: Chipset was already up to date.